# rails server not starting after switching form version 4 to version 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails version 3.2.6 and i recently downgraded from 4.0 because i wanted to work on a 3 version environment because the tutorial im following they are using version 3.
I am on a windows 7 machine and this is what i have done so far. 
i first did gem install rails -v 3.2.6
then i did gem uninstall rails, and chose the version i wanted to install.
i then downgraded the gem that were dependent on rails version 4 and i was not getting any errors when running bundle install.
now when i try to do rails s to see what broke on my page the server never starts and i get a bunch of file names:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'C:/Ruby200-         x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:81: warning: already initialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::OrmAdapter
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/orm_adapter-0.5.0/lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:81: warning: previous definition of OrmAdapter was here
: undefined method `migration_error=' for #<Class:0x000000053c7850> (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:65:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Beans/Desktop/TestMaker/config/initializers/devise.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:288:in `setup'
    from C:/Users/Beans/Desktop/TestMaker/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Users/Beans/Desktop/TestMaker/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Beans/Desktop/TestMaker/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from C:/Users/Beans/Desktop/TestMaker/config.ru:in `new'
    from C:/Users/Beans/Desktop/TestMaker/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

i know this might be a bunch of garbage to some, but if someone could help me that would be awesome. if you need more information, please let me know.
thank you in advance.

Comment: try to recreate rvm environment or you can create gemset then try it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i am using rails on windows, RVM does not work, so i used the pik gem and with that i changed my environment to 3.2.6 and then it worked fine.